# Split an IObservable and then combine after processing?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

After experimenting with IObservables, I've decided to test them for the processing of incoming messages over a message bus. Essentially I get an `IObservable<Request>` and the `Request` contains the necessary functions to reply to the response.

At a point during processing I have to deserialize the data and convert it from a Request to a Command object that contains what it actually needs to do. Command is not related to Request.

After deserializing it I transform it into the proper response, however in order to send the response I need the original Request object. I want to try and achieve this while maintaining high code readability. So far I've used extension methods and lambda expressions to get the following (where `requests` is the `IObservable<Request>`):

```
requestProcessor = requests
            .Deserialize<IdentityRequest>()
            .Where(idRequest => idRequest.Address != null)
            .Select(idRequest => new IdentityResponse() {Identity = identityTable[idRequest.Address.Address]})
            .Serialize()
            .Zip(requests, (response, request) => new {request = request, response = response})
            .Subscribe(data => data.request.Respond(data.response, ObjectTypes.IdentityResponse));
```

My question is, since all the commands before the `Zip` function take time to process, will the `Zip` operate on the same input object (ie. the original input, and also on the seperate processed input) if there are a constant stream of messages. How can I test this?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Depends on the version of the Framework you are using, Tuples could help here in 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it satisfactorily however there may be a better method. I created a monadic-like type that composes two types: a value which is the data being transformed; and a context which is the surrounding data.

It is something like the following:

```
 public class ComposedType<TValue, TContext>
 {
       public TValue Value { get; protected set; }
       public TContext Context { get; protected set; }

       public ComposedType(TValue value, TContext context)
       {
            Value = value;
            Context = context;
       }
  }
```

I also defined implicit operators for both context and value. There are also some associated extension methods that allow you to transform the value from one type to a new type.

If anyone has a better method though I welcome alternatives, and I'm going to leave this unanswered for a while.

Comment: It would be easier (although not necessarily more *clear*) to use [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) now.